# Binary searching using const pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

We should implement a function that uses binary search to check if a value `key` is in the array and give either true or false.

My goes like this:

```
bool binary_search(const int* begin, const int * end, int key){
    if(begin < end){
        int mid = (end-begin)/2;
        if(mid == key){
            return true;
        }else if (key < mid){
            int h = mid-1;
            end = &h;
            binary_search(begin, end, key);
        }else if (mid < key){
            int i = mid+1;
            begin = &i;
            binary_search(begin, end, key);
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

but it wouldn't give any output but instead it gives me the error.

`warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

I don't really understand what I have to do here so can someone explain me what is going wrong here?

Comment: The `binary_search(begin, end, key)` calls should probably have `return` in front of them.

Comment: @songyuanyao `end = &h;` is a bug - it should be `*end = h;` and `*begin = i;`

Comment: Note that when the code is indented to match the logic, there's nominally an `else` missing from the value checking code and the compiler might be complaining because there isn't a `return` on that path.  Granted, the three prior conditions are `if (key == mid)` and `else if (key < mid)` and `else if (key > mid)` and these cover all the cases, but the compiler might, or might not, spot that the third test is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of these if else statements

```
}else if (key < mid){
    int h = mid-1;
    end = &h;
    binary_search(begin, end, key);
}else if (mid < key){
    int i = mid+1;
    begin = &i;
    binary_search(begin, end, key);
}
```

the function returns nothing. That is these code blocks do not have return statements.

Moreover the function does not make sense because for example in these statements

```
int mid = (end-begin)/2;
if(mid == key){
```

there are compared key with an index of the array instead of comparing key with the value of the element in the array with index mid.

Or these statements

```
    int h = mid-1;
    end = &h;
```

also do not make sense because the variable end will store an address of the local variable h.

The function can be implemented the following way as it is shown in this demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool binary_search( const int *begin, const int *end, int key )
{
    if ( begin < end )
    {
        const int *mid = begin + ( end - begin ) / 2;

        if ( *mid < key ) return binary_search( ++mid, end, key );
        else if ( key < *mid ) return binary_search( begin, mid, key );
        else return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}   

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i <= a[N-1] + 1; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << i << " is present in the array - " 
                  << std::boolalpha << binary_search( a, a + N, i ) 
                  << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 is present in the array - false
1 is present in the array - true
2 is present in the array - false
3 is present in the array - true
4 is present in the array - false
5 is present in the array - true
6 is present in the array - false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `return` in all the possible branches.

Change

```
binary_search(begin, end, key);
```

to

```
return binary_search(begin, end, key);
```

to return the result from the recursive invocation.